# JSF selectOneButton with ajax update - setter 2 times invoked

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I use Primefaces 3.2 with ApacheMyfaces on WebSphere Application Server 8.

I have a selectOneButton with an ajax update inside.
When I switch the button, my setter firsts sets the value (int) to 0 and then to the value which is selected:

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{graph.view}" id="view">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="W" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="M" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Y" itemValue="3" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update=":optform:datecol"/>
</p:selectOneButton>
```

datecol is another selectComponent inside my form (optform).

Why does JSF first set the value to 0 and then to e.g. 2?

**SOLUTION**
It is a PrimeFaces selectOneButton Bug. See My question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611699/jsf-lifecycle-performed-2-times-with-primefaces-ajax) .

Best Regards
Veote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely what you are seeing is that the managed bean `graph` is being instantiated early in the JSF lifecycle, and only later in the `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES` phase is the appropriate value being set for the managed property `view`.  The managed bean regardless of scope, will be reinstantiated after each request due to the inherently stateless nature of the web.

For more information, BalusC has a great article on debugging the JSF Lifecycle with a step-by-step walkthrough on how to implement a custom PhaseListener that will help you understand and debug behavior like this in your application.

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html

Comment: This helped me to find out the reason! Thanks :)